# data.table linearly interpolating NA values without groups

Tags: r, data.table

I wanted to fill some NA values in a data.table without groups. Please consider this extract of data.table representing time and distances:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(time = seq(7173, 7195, 1), dist = c(31091.33, NA, 31100.00, 31103.27, NA, NA, NA, NA, 31124.98, NA,31132.81, NA, NA, NA, NA, 31154.19, NA, 31161.47, NA, NA, NA, NA, 31182.97))
DT<- data.table(df)
```

I want in the DT data.table, to fill NA values with a function depending on non-NA value before/after. As an example, writing a function in j to replace each instruction

```
DT[2, dist := (31091.33 + (31100-31091.33) / 2)]
```

then

```
DT[5:8, dist := (31103.27 + "something" * (31124.98 - 31103.27) / 5)]
```

etc...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code is explained inline. You can delete the temporary columns using `df[,dist_before := NULL]`, for example.

```r
library(data.table)
df=data.table(time=seq(7173,7195,1),dist=c(31091.33,NA,31100.00,31103.27,NA,NA,NA,
NA,31124.98,NA,31132.81,NA,NA,NA,NA,31154.19,NA,31161.47,NA,NA,NA,NA,31182.97))
df
#>     time     dist
#>  1: 7173 31091.33
#>  2: 7174       NA
#>  3: 7175 31100.00
#>  4: 7176 31103.27
#>  5: 7177       NA
#>  6: 7178       NA
#>  7: 7179       NA
#>  8: 7180       NA
#>  9: 7181 31124.98
#> 10: 7182       NA
#> 11: 7183 31132.81
#> 12: 7184       NA
#> 13: 7185       NA
#> 14: 7186       NA
#> 15: 7187       NA
#> 16: 7188 31154.19
#> 17: 7189       NA
#> 18: 7190 31161.47
#> 19: 7191       NA
#> 20: 7192       NA
#> 21: 7193       NA
#> 22: 7194       NA
#> 23: 7195 31182.97
#>     time     dist
# Carry forward the last non-missing observation
df[,dist_before := nafill(dist, "locf")]
# Bring back the next non-missing dist
df[,dist_after := nafill(dist, "nocb")]
# rleid will create groups based on run-lengths of values within the data.
# This means 4 NA's in a row will be grouped together, for example.
# We then count the missings and add 1, because we want the 
# last NA before the next non-missing to be less than the non-missing value.
df[, rle := rleid(dist)][,missings := max(.N +  1 , 2), by = rle][]
#>     time     dist dist_before dist_after rle missings
#>  1: 7173 31091.33    31091.33   31091.33   1        2
#>  2: 7174       NA    31091.33   31100.00   2        2
#>  3: 7175 31100.00    31100.00   31100.00   3        2
#>  4: 7176 31103.27    31103.27   31103.27   4        2
#>  5: 7177       NA    31103.27   31124.98   5        5
#>  6: 7178       NA    31103.27   31124.98   5        5
#>  7: 7179       NA    31103.27   31124.98   5        5
#>  8: 7180       NA    31103.27   31124.98   5        5
#>  9: 7181 31124.98    31124.98   31124.98   6        2
#> 10: 7182       NA    31124.98   31132.81   7        2
#> 11: 7183 31132.81    31132.81   31132.81   8        2
#> 12: 7184       NA    31132.81   31154.19   9        5
#> 13: 7185       NA    31132.81   31154.19   9        5
#> 14: 7186       NA    31132.81   31154.19   9        5
#> 15: 7187       NA    31132.81   31154.19   9        5
#> 16: 7188 31154.19    31154.19   31154.19  10        2
#> 17: 7189       NA    31154.19   31161.47  11        2
#> 18: 7190 31161.47    31161.47   31161.47  12        2
#> 19: 7191       NA    31161.47   31182.97  13        5
#> 20: 7192       NA    31161.47   31182.97  13        5
#> 21: 7193       NA    31161.47   31182.97  13        5
#> 22: 7194       NA    31161.47   31182.97  13        5
#> 23: 7195 31182.97    31182.97   31182.97  14        2
#>     time     dist dist_before dist_after rle missings
# .SD[,.I] will get us the row number relative to the group it is in. 
# For example, row 5 dist is calculated as
# dist_before + 1 * (dist_after - dist_before)/5
df[is.na(dist), dist := dist_before + .SD[,.I] *
                     (dist_after - dist_before)/(missings), by = rle]
df[]
#>     time     dist dist_before dist_after rle missings
#>  1: 7173 31091.33    31091.33   31091.33   1        2
#>  2: 7174 31095.67    31091.33   31100.00   2        2
#>  3: 7175 31100.00    31100.00   31100.00   3        2
#>  4: 7176 31103.27    31103.27   31103.27   4        2
#>  5: 7177 31107.61    31103.27   31124.98   5        5
#>  6: 7178 31111.95    31103.27   31124.98   5        5
#>  7: 7179 31116.30    31103.27   31124.98   5        5
#>  8: 7180 31120.64    31103.27   31124.98   5        5
#>  9: 7181 31124.98    31124.98   31124.98   6        2
#> 10: 7182 31128.90    31124.98   31132.81   7        2
#> 11: 7183 31132.81    31132.81   31132.81   8        2
#> 12: 7184 31137.09    31132.81   31154.19   9        5
#> 13: 7185 31141.36    31132.81   31154.19   9        5
#> 14: 7186 31145.64    31132.81   31154.19   9        5
#> 15: 7187 31149.91    31132.81   31154.19   9        5
#> 16: 7188 31154.19    31154.19   31154.19  10        2
#> 17: 7189 31157.83    31154.19   31161.47  11        2
#> 18: 7190 31161.47    31161.47   31161.47  12        2
#> 19: 7191 31165.77    31161.47   31182.97  13        5
#> 20: 7192 31170.07    31161.47   31182.97  13        5
#> 21: 7193 31174.37    31161.47   31182.97  13        5
#> 22: 7194 31178.67    31161.47   31182.97  13        5
#> 23: 7195 31182.97    31182.97   31182.97  14        2
#>     time     dist dist_before dist_after rle missings
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `approx` function to do linear interpolation.

For each group of `NA`s, get that subset of `DT` plus the rows before and after. Then apply `approx` to this subset of the `dist` vector, with the `n` argument of `approx` equal to the number of rows in the subset `.N`.

```
DT[, g := rleid(dist)]

DT[is.na(dist), dist := {
      i <- .I[c(1, .N)] + c(-1, 1)
      DT[i[1]:i[2], approx(dist, n = .N)$y[-c(1, .N)]]
  }, by = g]
```

Or, without `approx`

```
DT[, g := rleid(dist)]

DT[is.na(dist), dist := {
      i <- .I[c(1, .N)] + c(-1, 1)
      DT[i[1]:i[2], dist[1] + 1:(.N - 2)*(dist[.N] - dist[1])/(.N - 1)]
  }, by = g]
```

edit: since this answer was accepted I feel I should point out that other answers are faster and the second part of @dww's answer is basically my first code block but with the unnecessary grouping part removed (so it is simpler and faster).

Comment: in fact, i ask this question and afterwards, trying to make a non-linear approximation, so your solution is more adaptable to my needs. that's why i accepted your solution

Answer (score 8):

Using `library(zoo)`

```
DT[, dist := na.approx(dist)]
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to stick to base R functions rather than use another package, then you can do

```
DT[, dist := approx(.I, dist, .I)$y]
```

Answer (score 6):

2 other options:

1) rolling join:

```
DT[is.na(dist), dist := {
        x0y0 <- DT[!is.na(dist)][.SD, on=.(time), roll=Inf, .(time=x.time, dist=x.dist)]
        x1y1 <- DT[!is.na(dist)][.SD, on=.(time), roll=-Inf, .(time=x.time, dist=x.dist)]
        (x1y1$dist - x0y0$dist) / (x1y1$time - x0y0$time) * (time - x0y0$time) + x0y0$dist
    }]
DT
```

2) another close variant of smingerson answer using `nafill`

```
DT[, dist := {
    y0 <- nafill(dist, "locf")
    x0 <- nafill(replace(time, is.na(dist), NA), "locf")
    y1 <- nafill(dist, "nocb")
    x1 <- nafill(replace(time, is.na(dist), NA), "nocb")
    fifelse(is.na(dist), (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0) * (time - x0) + y0, dist)
}]
```

timing code:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
# df=data.frame(time=seq(7173,7195,1),dist=c(31091.33,NA,31100.00,31103.27,NA,NA,NA,NA,31124.98,NA,31132.81,NA,NA,NA,NA,31154.19,NA,31161.47,NA,NA,NA,NA,31182.97))
# DT=data.table(df)
nr <- 1e7
nNA <- nr/2
DT <- data.table(time=1:nr, dist=replace(rnorm(nr), sample(1:nr, nNA), NA_real_))

DT00 <- copy(DT)
DT01 <- copy(DT)
DT1 <- copy(DT)
DT20 <- copy(DT)
DT201 <- copy(DT)
DT202 <- copy(DT)
DT21 <- copy(DT)

mtd00 <- function() {
    DT00[, g := rleid(is.na(dist))]

    DT00[is.na(dist), dist := {
        i <- .I[c(1, .N)] + c(-1, 1)
        DT00[i[1]:i[2], approx(dist, n = .N)$y[-c(1, .N)]]
    }, by = g]
}

mtd01 <- function() {
    DT01[, g := rleid(is.na(dist))]

    DT01[is.na(dist), dist := {
        i <- .I[c(1, .N)] + c(-1, 1)
        DT01[i[1]:i[2], dist[1] + 1:(.N - 2)*(dist[.N] - dist[1])/(.N - 1)]
    }, by = g]
}

mtd1 <- function() {
    DT1[,dist_before := nafill(dist, "locf")]
    DT1[,dist_after := nafill(dist, "nocb")]
    DT1[, rle := rleid(dist)][,missings := max(.N +  1 , 2), by = rle][]
    DT1[is.na(dist), dist_before + .SD[,.I] *
            (dist_after - dist_before)/(missings), by = rle]
}


mtd20 <- function() {
    DT20[is.na(dist), {
        x0y0 <- DT20[!is.na(dist)][.SD, on=.(time), roll=Inf, .(time=x.time, dist=x.dist)]
        x1y1 <- DT20[!is.na(dist)][.SD, on=.(time), roll=-Inf, .(time=x.time, dist=x.dist)]
        (x1y1$dist - x0y0$dist) / (x1y1$time - x0y0$time) * (time - x0y0$time) + x0y0$dist
    }]
}

mtd201 <- function() {
    i <- DT201[, is.na(dist)]
    DT201[(i), {
        x0y0 <- DT201[(!i)][.SD, on=.(time), roll=Inf, .(time=x.time, dist=x.dist)]
        x1y1 <- DT201[(!i)][.SD, on=.(time), roll=-Inf, .(time=x.time, dist=x.dist)]
        (x1y1$dist - x0y0$dist) / (x1y1$time - x0y0$time) * (time - x0y0$time) + x0y0$dist
    }]
}

mtd202 <- function() {
    i <- DT201[is.na(dist), which=TRUE]
    DT201[i, {
        x0y0 <- DT201[-i][.SD, on=.(time), roll=Inf, .(time=x.time, dist=x.dist)]
        x1y1 <- DT201[-i][.SD, on=.(time), roll=-Inf, .(time=x.time, dist=x.dist)]
        (x1y1$dist - x0y0$dist) / (x1y1$time - x0y0$time) * (time - x0y0$time) + x0y0$dist
    }]
}


mtd21 <- function() {
    DT21[, {
        y0 <- nafill(dist, "locf")
        x0 <- nafill(replace(time, is.na(dist), NA), "locf")
        y1 <- nafill(dist, "nocb")
        x1 <- nafill(replace(time, is.na(dist), NA), "nocb")
        fifelse(is.na(dist), (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0) * (time - x0) + y0, dist)
    }]
}

bench::mark(
    #mtd00(), mtd01(), 
    #mtd1(),
    mtd20(), mtd201(), mtd202(),
    mtd21(), check=FALSE)
```

timings:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result            memory            time    gc            
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>            <list>            <list>  <list>        
1 mtd20()       1.19s    1.19s     0.838    1.01GB    1.68      1     2      1.19s <dbl [5,000,000]> <df[,3] [292 x 3~ <bch:t~ <tibble [1 x ~
2 mtd201()      1.12s    1.12s     0.894  954.06MB    0.894     1     1      1.12s <dbl [5,000,000]> <df[,3] [341 x 3~ <bch:t~ <tibble [1 x ~
3 mtd202()      1.16s    1.16s     0.864  858.66MB    1.73      1     2      1.16s <dbl [5,000,000]> <df[,3] [392 x 3~ <bch:t~ <tibble [1 x ~
4 mtd21()    729.93ms 729.93ms     1.37   763.11MB    1.37      1     1   729.93ms <dbl [10,000,000~ <df[,3] [215 x 3~ <bch:t~ <tibble [1 x ~
```

---

edit: to address comment on using `is.na(dist)` multiple times:

```
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 1e7
nNA <- nr/2
DT <- data.table(time=1:nr, dist=replace(rnorm(nr), sample(1:nr, nNA), NA_real_))
DT20 <- copy(DT)
DT201 <- copy(DT)
DT202 <- copy(DT)

mtd20 <- function() {
    DT20[is.na(dist), dist := {
        x0y0 <- DT20[!is.na(dist)][.SD, on=.(time), roll=Inf, .(time=x.time, dist=x.dist)]
        x1y1 <- DT20[!is.na(dist)][.SD, on=.(time), roll=-Inf, .(time=x.time, dist=x.dist)]
        (x1y1$dist - x0y0$dist) / (x1y1$time - x0y0$time) * (time - x0y0$time) + x0y0$dist
    }]
}

mtd201 <- function() {
    i <- DT201[, is.na(dist)]
    DT201[(i), dist := {
        x0y0 <- DT201[(!i)][.SD, on=.(time), roll=Inf, .(time=x.time, dist=x.dist)]
        x1y1 <- DT201[(!i)][.SD, on=.(time), roll=-Inf, .(time=x.time, dist=x.dist)]
        (x1y1$dist - x0y0$dist) / (x1y1$time - x0y0$time) * (time - x0y0$time) + x0y0$dist
    }]
}

mtd202 <- function() {
    i <- DT201[is.na(dist), which=TRUE]
    DT201[i, dist := {
        x0y0 <- DT201[-i][.SD, on=.(time), roll=Inf, .(time=x.time, dist=x.dist)]
        x1y1 <- DT201[-i][.SD, on=.(time), roll=-Inf, .(time=x.time, dist=x.dist)]
        (x1y1$dist - x0y0$dist) / (x1y1$time - x0y0$time) * (time - x0y0$time) + x0y0$dist
    }]
}
```

timings:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result                    memory             time     gc               
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>                    <list>             <list>   <list>           
1 mtd20()      24.1ms   25.8ms      37.5    1.01GB    13.6     11     4      294ms <df[,2] [10,000,000 x 2]> <df[,3] [310 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [15 x 3]>
2 mtd201()     24.8ms   25.6ms      38.2  954.07MB     8.19    14     3      366ms <df[,2] [10,000,000 x 2]> <df[,3] [398 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [17 x 3]>
3 mtd202()       24ms   25.6ms      38.3   76.39MB     8.22    14     3      365ms <df[,2] [10,000,000 x 2]> <df[,3] [241 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [17 x 3]>
```

Not seeing much diff in timings when reduce the number of `is.na(dist)` calls

Comment: `is.na(dist)` is computed 3 times, it could be computed once and re-used

Comment: it is not easy to compare timings when there are mixed units (`ms`/`us`)

Comment: I cannot replicate the results on the benchmark.  ```DT_x <- copy(DT)``` probably needs to be at the top of each function call. The update-by-reference happens within function calls.

Comment: @Cole thanks, i am always worried that the copy will impact the variance of timings. hence i tend to leave it outside. with regards to the update by reference, 1) the memory is already allocated, 2) code does not assume the calculated column has been pre-computed nor use the computed column and 3) column plonking occurs on each repetition and hence hopefully has less of an impact on the timings. for the former, you might want to time `bench::mark(copy(DT), copy(DT))`

Comment: The timings are largely depending on how many NAs there are. The first function call updates-by-reference and replaces the NAs with values. All subsequent calls have nothing to replace. For the ```1e7``` example, with ```copy(DT)``` taking 27 ms, the ```mtd20()``` call took 1.43s using copy and *only* 30 ms if I remove the copy from the function.

Comment: @Cole, i removed the update by reference for those functions that i timed. using only `nafill` and `fifelse` is fastest

Comment: This looks great. One last question. Why do you think the rolling join has a different output than the ```nafill``` method? Also, I made a FR at github regarding this if you are interested: [FR4036](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4066)

Comment: The rolling join returns values only for NA locations. The other method returns the whole vector

Answer (score 6):

Here's an [rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp) approach that loops through everything once with additional pass for all NA elements.

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = '
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector rcpp_approx2D(IntegerVector x, NumericVector y) {
  double x_start = 0, y_start = 0, slope = 0;
  int count = 0;

  NumericVector y1 = clone(y); //added to not update-by-reference

  for(int i = 0; i < y1.size(); ++i){
    if (NumericVector::is_na(y1[i])){
      count++;
    } else {
      if (count != 0) {
        x_start = x[i-(count+1)];
        y_start = y1[i-(count+1)];
        slope = (y1[i] - y_start) / (x[i]- x_start);
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++){
          y1[i-(count-j)] = y_start + slope * (x[i - (count - j)] - x_start);
        }
        count = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  return(y1);
}
')
```

Then in R:

```
DT[, rcpp_approx2D(time, dist)]
```